Open file on keyboard shortcut in VS Code
I have a file "cheatcheet.md" in my documents directory. I would like to open it with a single keyboard shortcut (something unused like Ctrl+i n), instead of going into Menu > File > Open File... and navigate to file.
I have tried few suggestions in keybindings.json suggested by SO, but they either error out or do nothing.

You can use the extension I wrote: HTML Related Links
It has a command: htmlRelatedLinks.openFile
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i n",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${workspaceFolder}/cheatcheet.md",
      "method": "vscode.open"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }


What has happened to traffic on SO - at least for this tag?  Seems way down.

You can simply use this keybinding for vscode.open:
{
  "key": "ctrl+i n",
  "command": "vscode.open",
  "args": "file:///C:/Program Files/Git/etc/bash.bashrc"
}

Note: use forward slashes.

Thank you a ton. It seems thou that it wants to open local file, even if I'm connected to remote environment via Remote SSH. Strange...
